# could not balanced large dataset

Tags: r, oversampling

i tried various techniques such as oversampling, undersampling, ROSE and both(oversampling and undersampling) on a imbalanced dataset to balance a dataset. when i applied all these techniques on a small dataset then these techniques perfectly work

```
library(ROSE)

> table(df4$Price)

     0      1 
100020   1249 
> data.rose <- ROSE(Price~., data=df4, seed=3, N = 200040)$data
>  table(data.rose$Price)

     0      1 
 99960 100080 
# Oversampling
> data.balanced.over <- ovun.sample(Price ~ ., data = df4, method = "over",N = 200040)$data
 table(data.balanced.over$Price)

     0      1 
100020 100020 
> data.balanced.both <- ovun.sample(Price ~ ., data = df4, method = "both",N = 200040)$data
> table(data.balanced.both$Price)

     0      1 
 99903 100137 
> data.balanced.under <- ovun.sample(Price ~ ., data = df4, method = "under",N = 2538)$data
> table(data.balanced.under$Price)

   0    1 
1289 1249
```

but i when i applied all these techniques on a large dataset then i got error

```
> table(mydata$Price)

       0        1 
33003944  1150753 
> data.rose <- ROSE(Price~., data=mydata, seed=3)$data
Error in omnibus.balancing(formula, data, subset, na.action, N, p, method = "rose",  : 
  Too few observations.
> data.balanced.over <- ovun.sample(Price ~ ., data = mydata, method = "over",N = 66007888)$data
Error in (function (formula, data, method, subset, na.action, N, p = 0.5,  : 
  Too few observations.
>  data.balanced.under <- ovun.sample(Price ~ ., data = mydata, method = "under",N = 2301506)$data
Error in (function (formula, data, method, subset, na.action, N, p = 0.5,  : 
  Too few observations.
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: data_frame <- fread(file.choose(),sep=",",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,select=c(1,2,3,4),colClasses=c("as.numeric","as.Date","as.numeric","as.character"))                      data_frame2 <- fread(file.choose(),sep=",",header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,select=c(1,2,3,4,5),colClasses=c("as.numeric","as.Date","as.numeric","as.numeric","as.numeric"))   mydata<-rbind(df1, df2)   table(mydata$Price)

       0        1 
33003944  1150753

Comment: > data.rose <- ROSE(Price~., data=mydata, seed=3)$data
Error in omnibus.balancing(formula, data, subset, na.action, N, p, method = "rose",  : 
  Too few observations.